# How can I avoid or change the Error Format via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, format, formula

I have to export regularly from an external program an Excel table.

In this table, there are phone numbers in a list. Those exported numbers give me a kind of format error that can´t be fixed changing the format to "Standard" or "number", the only way that is accepted is when I click in the error box and press "convert to a number".

[image: Format error]

The issue comes because the formulas in my Macro won´t accept the format and I can´t let my co-workers change it manually.

Is there any way via VB to change the format of those cells automatically?

I tried in VB and also manually:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

Comment: What about `Selection.ClearFormats ` and then `Selection = Selection.value`?

Comment: Selection.ClearFormats does not change anything (only the color).  Regardings Selections.Value I´m not sure I fully understand how it here applies, but by itself it shows me an error because I don´t declare any value to it.

Comment: Sub Covert_to_num()
Range("A1:B4").Value = Range("A1:B4").Value
End Sub

Comment: Doe this answer your question? [Excel: How to force cell evaluation](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365)

Comment: You´re right, problem was another and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Notice I've selected all those cells with numbers but being recognized as text (same case as yours). Then this code fix it:

```
Selection.ClearFormats
Selection = Selection.Value
```

After executing code:

[image]

Now all values are being read as numeric (notice how aligment has changed)